# unable to hide the Recurrence , Workspace & All Day Event from a content type

Tags: list, development, content-type, recurring-events

I have created a new custom content type , that have the Built-in Event as it parent, and i want to hide the following columns from my new content type:-

- Recurrence
- Workspace
- All Day Event

but seems they are greyed-out as follow, so i can not hide them:-

[image]

can anyone adivce on this please?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using on-premise env. you can use next power shell script to remove fieldref's from content type (or another option - you can set this fields to "hidden"):

$web = Get-SPWeb http://your_portal

$ct = $web.ContentTypes["your_content_type"]

$spFieldLink = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLink ($web.Fields["your_field"])

$ct.FieldLinks.Delete($spFieldLink.Id)

$ct.Update()

$web.Dispose()

If this is SPOnline env., you can use jslink's to hide this fields on the forms and list view by the javascript.

Comment: but why i need to write a power shell script to hide the columns ? this should be available from the content type settings using browser ?

Comment: also can you adivce how i can hide the column from the CT instead of removing the column ?

Comment: also i can not find a way to get the columns id .. can you adivce from where i can get their ids ?